# Not able to understand the auto generated cucumber step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have a part of feature as

```
And I should see "Thank you for your interest. We will soon send an email with activation instructions." within "span class="notificationText""
```

and

an auto generated step

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" within "([^"]*)"notificationText"([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1, arg2, arg3|
end
```

I am unable to interpret it. I am trying to fit the following test in it(from http://www.cowboycoded.com/2011/01/05/better-web-steps-for-cucumber-with-capybara/), but unable to understand what arguments stand for what.

```
  with_scope(select,:css_id) do
      page.should have_selector("h1",:text=>text)
  end
```

Comment: I don't recommend putting html code in the step definitions. That's not the intent of Cucumber. See: [You're cuking it wrong](http://elabs.se/blog/15-you-re-cuking-it-wrong).

Comment: Page is getting blocked, not able to open it.

Comment: Try the Ruby5 episode at http://ruby5.envylabs.com/episodes/104-episode-102-august-13-2010/stories/881-you-re-cuking-it-wrong where the post is discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually cucumber generates the script file based on what we given in the feature file, so in this file wherever we used some text inside the single or double quotes, these text are take as dynamic text, so every quoted text can be taken as an dynamic arguments

Those arguments are going to passed at runtime by user.